Add constraint parameter for minimum hours between shifts for employee scheduling
I'm trying to modify the constraint in the employee scheduling quickstart to support parameters but it doesn't seem to work.
I modified the code to be like this, not sure why it isn't working.
Constraint atLeast10HoursBetweenTwoShifts(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
return constraintFactory.forEach(Shift.class)
        .join(Shift.class, equal(Shift::getEmployee), lessThanOrEqual(Shift::getEnd, Shift::getStart))
        .join(ConstraintParameters.class)
        .filter((firstShift,
                secondShift, constraintParameters) -> {
             return Duration.between(firstShift.getEnd(), secondShift.getStart()).toHours() < constraintParameters.minRestHours();
        })
        .penalize(HardSoftBigDecimalScore.ONE_HARD,
                (firstShift, secondShift, constraintParameters) -> {
                    int breakLength = (int) Duration.between(firstShift.getEnd(), secondShift.getStart()).toMinutes();
                    return (constraintParameters.minRestHours() * 60) - breakLength;
                })
        .asConstraint("At least 10 hours between 2 shifts");
}



Please describe "not working." What are you seeing? What do you expect to see?

There might not be a ConstraintParameters instance known to join with.
Check if your solution class has a ConstraintParameters field annotated with @ProblemFactProperty.
